# PHP regex with word boundary after escaped character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I recently stumbled on this problem, and I can't figure out why it is happening.

Consider the following example: I have a random text and an array with some programming languages. In a loop I will match each language as whole words, using regular expression and with word boundaries \b before and after, and then print a URL.

```
$string = 'I don\'t know C e C++ so well, but I can code in PHP.';
$languages = [
    'PHP' => '/php/',
    'C++' => '/cpp/',
    'C' => '/c/',
];

foreach ($languages as $name => $uri) {
    $regex = '/\b' . preg_quote($name, '/') . '\b/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
        echo "For {$name} information refer to http://foo.bar{$uri}" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I would expect the following output:

```
For PHP information refer to http://foo.bar/php/
For C++ information refer to http://foo.bar/cpp/
For C information refer to http://foo.bar/c/
```

However, the output I get is:

```
For PHP information refer to http://foo.bar/php/
For C information refer to http://foo.bar/c/
```

The word boundary (\b) immediately after the escaped plus sign (+) does not work as I expected.

If I replace that \b with [^\w] it works, but I am not 100% sure this approach wouldn't backfire on me.

Why does this happen, and what to do to get the result I need?

Comment: There is no word boundary after `+` character since `+` is a non-word character.

Comment: It does work, @wp78de. I was thinking `(^|[^\w])C\+\+([^\w]|$)` but your expression is more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to solve this is using lookarounds to asserts word characters instead of boundaries, e.g. `(?<!\w)c\+\+(?!\w)`:

```
$string = 'I don\'t know C e C++ so well, but I can code in PHP.';
$languages = [
    'PHP' => '/php/',
    'C++' => '/cpp/',
    'C' => '/c/',
];

foreach ($languages as $name => $uri) {
    $regex = '/(?<!\w)' . preg_quote($name, '/') . '(?!\w)/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
        echo "For {$name} information refer to http://foo.bar{$uri}" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
For PHP information refer to http://foo.bar/php/
For C++ information refer to http://foo.bar/cpp/
For C information refer to http://foo.bar/c/
```

Comment: Thank you. I was having a similar issue and was wondering why I couldn't match certain words consistently.